# Stepper motor controlled by C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm having trouble with my stepper motor. I wrote arduino code and it works when commands are sent from a serial terminal or tera term. When I press "R" stepper motor rotates continuously, when I press "P", the motor stops rotating. My question is why those commands don't work when sent from a C# app? When I try the stepper motor just turns one step. Is there any difference between sending commands from serial monitor and a C# app?

```
void loop()
{  
   if (Serial.available() > 0)
   {
      int command = Serial.read();
   {

   if (command == 'R')
   {
      do {
         stepper.runSpeed();
      } while (Serial.available() == 0); 
      Serial.read();    
   } 
   else if (command == 'P')
   {
      stepper.stop();
   }
}
```

C# code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort.WriteLine("R");
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort.WriteLine("P");
}
```

Comment: See if BaudRate and Port name is correctly selected.

Comment: my c# app connection is good. I have few others projects and works fine. Problem is serial communication and how i can send commands form c# which will continious rotate stepp motor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerialPort.WriteLine()` adds `"\r\n"`. The `\r` will immediately terminate your `do{ ... }while()` loop on the receiving end.

So use

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //serialPort.WriteLine("R");
     serialPort.Write("R");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `serial.parseInt();` instead of `serial.read` and send a string from c#.